# AWS container service: set max_map_count

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, docker

I'm trying to run Elasticsearch on AWS container service. Here the documentation that I'm following: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-cli-run-prod-mode

> The vm_map_max_count setting should be set permanently in
>   /etc/sysctl.conf:
>
> $ grep vm.max_map_count /etc/sysctl.conf
>
> vm.max_map_count=262144
>
> To apply the setting on a live system type: sysctl -w
>   vm.max_map_count=262144

Is there any way to set the vm.max_map_count via script? I don't want to do it manually every time I run a new container.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution:

1. create an empty container
2. Launch an EC2 inside the previous container: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html
3. Add the user data (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) as follow:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> echo vm.max_map_count=262144 >> /etc/sysctl.conf
> sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
> ```

Now the EC2 instance is properly configured.

Answer (score 1):

You could still set it permanently in ***/etc/sysctl.conf*** as per you've mentioned in your Q. Didn't it work?

**OR**

as per this [ticket](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4397) you could set it up as follows:

> sysctl -qw vm.max_map_count=65535

Hope it helps!

Comment: Do I need to run this command on the host machine? The issue is that I need to do it on the host everytime an instance is launched, so I can't use autoscaling.

Comment: So you update the configuration and make a new VM image. Use that image to scale up the cluster.

Comment: I discovered I can actually create an AMI for ECS, but it's not required, see my answer.